# How to read .ost file in asp.net C# console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, office365, office-automation

```
  //Set NameSpcae for Outlook "Mapi" is by Default Name
                NameSpace outlookNs = null;
                DailyLog("Start Outlook Application Mapi", "");
                outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                DailyLog("End Outlook Application Start Mapi", "");
                DailyLog("Start Outlook Application Logon", "");
                outlookNs.Logon(null, null, false, false);
                DailyLog("End Outlook Application Logon", "");
                Console.WriteLine("Set By Default Name MAPI");
          
                //Add Pst File in OutLook
                Console.WriteLine("Adding PST File From Path : " + pstFilePath);
                DailyLog("Set PST File Path :- " + pstFilePath, "");
                **outlookNs.AddStore(pstFilePath);**
                DailyLog("Set PST File Path :- " + pstFilePath, "");
                Console.WriteLine("SET PST File To Successfully.");
                DailyLog("SET PST File To Successfully.","");
                if (Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isSendRecieved"]) == 1)
                {
                    outlookNs.SendAndReceive(true);
                }
```

i get this error  message "The Outlook data file (.pst) failed to load for this session"

```
    <add key="MailPort" value="25"/>
    <add key="MailServer" value="smtp1.projectstoday.com"/>
```

also used the port and server

what should i add the port number and Mail server for Office365

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you deal with Exchange accounts you may consider using the EWS or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) (in case of Office365) instead, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.